# Neo4j merge chain unexpectedly slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running neo4j 2.2.4

I have a large chain of merge that matches/creates a bunch of nodes and relationships, as well as setting properties.

All my node merges are based on one index.

With an almost empty database (thus all merges will end up creating nodes/relationships), I get the following timings:

```
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 40
Relationships created: 87
Properties set: 62
Labels added: 40
1557 ms
Total database accesses: 688
```

Now 40 nodes and 87 relationships aren't that many and I'd expect the query to execute much faster than 1.5 seconds.

Below is the timings for a larger query with a similar style.

```
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 214
Relationships created: 454
Properties set: 469
Labels added: 214
298711 ms
```

I'm a bit surprised at how slow this is. Is there anything I might be doing wrong here?

---

Edit:

The beginning of the query looks like this, and the rest are in a very similar style:

```
merge (e1:Label { id: "e1" })
merge (e2:Label { id: "e2" })
merge (e1)-[:R1]->(e2)
merge (e3:Label { id: "e3" })
merge (e2)-[r1:R2]->(e3)
  on create set r1.p = "v" 
  on match set r1.p = "v"
merge (e4:Label { id: "e4" })
merge (e4)-[:R1]->(e3)
merge (e1)-[:R2]->(e4)
merge (e5:Label { id: "e5" })
merge (e2)-[r2:R3]->(e5)
  on create set r2.p = "v"
  on match set r2.p = "v"                                                                                          
merge (e6:Label { id: "e6" })
merge (e6)-[:R1]->(e5)
merge (e1)-[:R3]->(e6)
```

Indexes

```
  ON :Label(id) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
```

Constraints

```
  ON (e:Label) ASSERT e.id IS UNIQUE
```

---

Edit 2:

The profile for the ~40 node query are captured here:
https://gist.github.com/haoyangnz/c59b99a9a99a87edf00a

The profile for the ~200 node query failed due to StackOverflowError

Comment: Can you show (part of) of your query?

Comment: @DavidtenHove Added.

Comment: how big is your query in total?

Comment: @MichaelHunger you can see from the stats - my database is mostly empty when I ran them so the number of merges equals the sum of node/relationship created

Comment: can you share a PROFILE output from your query?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I can share a profile soon (after my commute) but I would imagine it be very similar to what you'll get if you run that query - you just need to run it with more nodes/relationships (see the numbers in the question) and you should get a similar order of magnitude in timings

Comment: can you still share it it as a gist or dropbox link, you have the code that can generate the statement :) I don't and don't have the time do do it manually .

Comment: @MichaelHunger yea will do soon :-)

Comment: @MichaelHunger profile added.

Comment: can you also add the actual query to the gist? thanks a lot

Comment: @MichaelHunger I've addd the query to the gist. Now because the data are sensitive I had to censor the actual data by replacing all of them with SensitiveData. Sorry about that. Obviously, the actual node merges are all based on different ids, not the same dummy id.

Comment: @MichaelHunger If you want to run the query, rather than just looking at the structure, I can hash the actual data rather than replacing them with the same placeholder. But I will need to do that a bit later.

Comment: In general, I would probably split up the query, into doing individual merge statements both for nodes and rels.

Answer (score 3):

You may try merge all the nodes and after that merge relationships. Like
`Merge (a:A{id:1}), (b:B{id:2}) with a, b Merge (a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b)`. 
And by separating merge it maight be easier to find the problem. You might need index for id, like in my case. But i'm not sure if it helps.

Comment: OK Thanks - I'll give this a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example query on console.neo4j.org and it finished in a few ms:

> Query took 187 ms and returned no rows.  Updated the graph - created 6
>   nodes and 7 relationships set 8 properties Result Details

What OS are you running on? Did you change any of the default settings?

Comment: Well yes - I get roughly the same timings for 6 nodes created - but as you can see from my timings, they're for ~40 and ~200 respectively

Comment: Default settings on a Mac